# Smooth Scroll is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I just followed a youtube tutorial to get smoothscroll working. The guy in the video set these at the bottom of

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollTo/2.1.2/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-localScroll/1.4.0/jquery.localScroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
```

where the .js file contains:

```html
$('.nav').localscroll();
```

In my main, my sidebar links are:

```html
<div id="sidebar">
 <h4><a href="#Atoms" >Atoms, Elements and the Periodic Table</a></h4>
 <h4><a href="#Group-1">Group 1</a></h4>
 <h4><a href="#Group-7">Group 7</a></h4>
 <h4><a href="#Group-0">Group 0 - Noble Gases</a></h4>
</div>
```

so I used #sidebar as the target in the .js folder. (Is that correct?)

In my .css file, the id sidebar is:

```html
#sidebar {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 5%;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  overflow: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  top: 60px; 
  bottom:0;
}
```

I believe my syntax is correct (although Im new to coding, it may not be). However, the smooth-scroll doesnt work, any ideas why?

Cheers!

Comment: `<div id="sidebar">` means you should use `$("#sidebar").localscroll();` and your css should be `#sidebar { ...`.  Or you could change your div to `<div class='sidebar'>`

Comment: Apologies - I have updated my code correctly now, I was in the middle of swapping and playing when I posted! I beleive what you put is what I tried originally

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question other than "is this correct" - if it works, it's probably correct...  does it work?  What does it do / not do?  What's the issue/question?

Comment: No - it doesnt work. Issue is that the smooth scroll is not working correctly, and wanted to know firstly - is my syntax correct and if so, why isnt it working

Comment: `smooth scroll is not working correctly` means??

Comment: It means its not working... Instead of "smooth scrolling" to the anchor, it just "jumps"

Comment: "jumps" is very different from "does nothing" which would also be classified as "not working" (also, "not working" might mean it blows up your monitor every time, again, very different) - which is why we have to ask the questions that may seem obvious to you with it in front of you.

Comment: Try adding `$(window).on("notify.serialScroll", function() { console.log("scroll"); });` to see if your getting the scroll events.  Looks like it's not kicking in but hitting the default `#target` jump to

Comment: Look in the browser console (F11, console tab) to see if you have syntax errors

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND js/smoothscroll.js

Comment: Well, there's your answer :)  For future reference, always add a temporary `alert("file.js")` in your custom js file to ensure it's loaded.  Looks like your external file is not in a `js/` subfolder, try moving it or changing to `<script src="smoothscroll.js"></script>` (whereever you've put smoothscroll.js)

Comment: Okay, I have done - I now get the error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).localscroll is not a function
    at smoothscroll.js:1

Comment: `.localScroll` (capital S)

Comment: (I looked at the links you provided, removing the .min part: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-localScroll/1.4.0/jquery.localScroll.js)

Comment: hahah my bad! Well, no error is being kicked out now... but it still does not "smoothscroll" and still just jumps?

Comment: Just tried removing the min part, no difference - still "jumps"

Comment: Must be something else you've done that's not in the question.  Try recreating it on jsfiddle.net and we might be able to have a look.  Here's one working, with the bare minimum to confirm that smooth scroll plugin does work as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/b3hnuj1p/  (with your sidebar css: https://jsfiddle.net/b3hnuj1p/1/)

Comment: Any more errors in the console?   I had to change http to https in jsfiddle.

Comment: Never used this jsfiddle thing. I made an account and put all my code in, but dont know how to get the share link?

Comment: No need for an account (too late...) when you click save it will update the url, just copy url here

Comment: Thanks - https://jsfiddle.net/ryanlb96/uqheLw98/2/

I also have 2 more .js files (nav.js for the menu bar at the top, and template.js which links in my styles, copyright box, box above that (grey one) and the fonts)

Comment: Look in the console, it gives two helpful errors "Mixed Content: The page at was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS." then "jQuery is not defined" and "$ is not defined".  A quick tweak to your code to get jquery via https and it works fine.  https://jsfiddle.net/b3hnuj1p/1/

Comment: You can't include local files in jsfiddle (nav/template) so I commented those out and it still worked ok.  Check the console on your original app again and see if gives the Mixed Content error (and change to https if it does)

Comment: Console doesnt kick out any errors at all now

Comment: http://ryanteaches.com/gcsechemistry is the site where you can see it all in action

Comment: Does that help? Still not sure why its not working

Comment: Change `$("#sidebar").localScroll();` to `$(function() { $("#sidebar").localScroll(); });`   - if you load your page (doesn't smoothscroll) then go to console and enter `$("#sidebar").localScroll();` - it then smoothscrolls.  So putting it in document ready does the same thing, so should be ok.   In jsfiddle, all the code goes in doument ready.

Comment: You, my friend, are a genius. Thank you!